# How can i remotely access the windows services of a remote host in workgroup computers?

Tags: c#, service, wmi, servicecontroller, workgroup

I am writing an application which is used to manipulate the windows services. My computer is in a workgroup. But i couldn't get access to the machine. I've tried Impersonation using LogonUser(). But is not working. I am able to manipulate using Remote Desktop connection, however i couldn't access programatically.

```
    ImpersonateUser ImpersonatedUser = new ImpersonateUser();
    ImpersonatedUser.Impersonate(Domain, Username, password);
    ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("servicename", host_name);
    Console.WriteLine("Success."); 


  //impersonation.
public class ImpersonateUser
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(
    String lpszUsername,
    String lpszDomain,
    String lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType,
    int dwLogonProvider,
    ref IntPtr phToken);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
    private static IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
    private static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser;
    // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand that it
    // runs with FullTrust.
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Impersonate(string domainName, string userName, string password)
    {
        //try
        {
            // Use the unmanaged LogonUser function to get the user token for
            // the specified user, domain, and password.
            const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
            // Passing this parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.
            const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
            tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            // ---- Step - 1
            // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
            bool returnValue = LogonUser(
            userName,
            domainName,
            password,
            LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
            ref tokenHandle); // tokenHandle - new security token
            if (false == returnValue)
            {
                int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
            }
            // ---- Step - 2
            WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
            // ---- Step - 3
            {
                impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
            }
        }
    }
    // Stops impersonation
    public void Undo()
    {
        impersonatedUser.Undo();
        // Free the tokens.
        if (tokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any progress on this? Did my answer help you?

Comment: I've found that we cannot impersonate the user on workgroup computer.
though we impersonate, WorkGrooup computer force the user to be guest. Thus, if we want to login as the user we need to change the registry value forceguest=0 .

Comment: If you have found a solution to your question, you should write your own answer and mark it accepted, for other users with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that we cannot impersonate the user on workgroup computer. though we impersonate, WorkGrooup computer force the user to be guest. Thus, if we want to login as the user we need to change the registry value forceguest=0